# How do I refresh HTML table after performing POST request in ngOnInit()?

Tags: html, angular, post, ngoninit

Upon visiting the component `invoices.ts` , it looks in the background for some updates and applies them to the existing ones. Otherwise when the user has no existing invoices, it will perform a POST request to create them. However, when the user visits the component the POST and PUT operations are called in the `ngOnInit()` , i still see an empty table untill I refresh the page. How do i automatically refresh the HTML table to fill the newly made invoices without using `window.location.reload()' ?

`invoice.component.ts`

```
  ngOnInit() {

  this.auth.getProfile().subscribe((profile : any) => {
  this.userName = profile.user.username;
  this.email = profile.user.email;
}

  this.getAndUpdateInvoices();
}


getAndUpdateInvoices() {

   this.invoiceService.getInvoicesn().subscribe((data : any) => {
     this.invoices= data.invoice;

      this.createUpdate();

})


createUpdate() {

  this.createInvoice({
              client: data.Client,

 ***etc
  })
}


createInvoice(invoice) {
this.invoiceService.newInvoice(invoice).subscribe((data: any) => {
  if (!data.success) {
    console.log(data.message);
  } else {
    console.log(data.message);
  }
});
 }


 this.invoiceService.updateInvoice(this.invoice).subscribe((data: any) => {
              if (!data.success) {
                console.log(data.message);              
              } else {
                console.log(data.message);
              }
            });
```

}

In my `invoice.component.html`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices"  >
<td> {{invoice.hours}} </td>
```

Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Can you add the following lines of your HTML file to see how are you using the invoice variable ? please

Comment: i have added a line how I am using the table

Comment: So the answer proposed should works, call this.getAndUpdateInvoices() into the createInvoice method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call the method which is being used for fetching all the data from your service class here :

```
createInvoice(invoice) {
    this.invoiceService.newInvoice(invoice).subscribe((data: any) => {
        if (!data.success) {
            console.log(data.message);
        } else {
            console.log(data.message);

           -----HERE----

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i dont know what you mean, can you explain please?

Comment: your html will 'refresh' when your invoices var will be change. If you want to get your invoices after the call of createInvoice, you need to call getAndUpdateInvoices() into the createInvoice()

Comment: that is exactly what I mean thank you for explaining @Loïc